# Group by two columns, where one of them is not null

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, group-by

I have the following table:

```
c1   c2
1    5
1    6
2    5
2    null
3    null
3    null

expected: 1
```

This is NxM table, where N is number of distinct values of c1, and M is number of distinct values of c2, so, there are always the same number of pairs (c1,c2) for different c1.

I want to select value from column с1, for which there are not a single corresponding null in c2.

I have tried to do GROUP BY(c1, null) HAVING (COUNT(*) = 0), but it didn't work.

How can I do it?

Comment: where is your table t2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the column you want to be distinct and take only those groups having no `NULL` value in `c2`. The `case` is used to sum up those conditions

```
select c1
from your_table
group by c1
having sum(case when c2 is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

use not exists

```
select c1 from table_name t1
where not exists ( select 1 from table_name t2 where t1.c1=t2.c1 
                               and t2.c2 is null)
```

Comment: there is only one table with 2 columns

Comment: @e.e yap i used only one table this corelated subquery

Answer (score 0):

Apart from answers already given, you can also achieve the result using `NOT IN` operator as following:

```
Select distinct c1 from your_table
Where c1 not in 
(select t.c1 from your_table t
Where t.c2 is null 
and t.c1 is not null);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: thanks! that must work too, but the problem is that my table is temporary, so it would be a little hard to select twice from it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this

```
select c1
from your_table
group by c1
having count(c1)=count(c2);
```

Answer (score -1):

select c1 from table1
where c2 is not null;